# Customize tile labels in exploded view

Tags: gnome

In Ubuntu exploded view the name under the tile for a VSCode window looks like this (imagine this is one of multiple windows in exploded view)

[image]

So it goes {File} - {Project} - Visual Studio Code.

I'd like to be get rid of the {File}, or at least make {Project} first which is what my eyes are looking for. Might seem like a nitpick - but I'm aiming for seamless window switching.

PS for context: I also have a gnome extension which shows all tile labels at once rather than the user having to mouseover tiles to see the labels.

Comment: is it possible to share the link of extension you have mentioned? editing code with in the extension may help to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: @UnKNOWn that's a good tip, but I can't find the extension source :( when I come across it again I'll remember this tip